# Wireless unable to connect after clean-up

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I opened a laptop to clean the dust inside it (I've done it before, several times, on different laptops). I put all the components and made all the connections. Everything works fine, except the wireless adapter. Windows 7 is able to detect wireless networks, but it cannot connect to them. (Those networks were previously usable).

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the wireless chip was damaged. A new chip worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

After cleaning, you may of switched the external wifi switch OFF. Check your laptop for the wireless kill switch. It will be either on the edges, or a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: The wireless switch is above the keyboard and is turned on. If i turn it off, Windows will no longer search for networks. I saw now that the wifi switch is blinking.